# Can i save modification in compressed file folder?

Tags: compression, zip

When modifying documents that are directly opened from compressed file folders like RAR or Zip, I normally close them without dragging the files out of the rar or zip file. I used to do this in the past and the modifications were not saved. But sometimes it worked, why?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. You're being too vague. Add more information about what program you're actually using. We cannot guess why it sometimes work and why it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly modify a file inside a `.zip` or `.rar` file.

To modify a file inside a compresed file you have to extract the file, modify it and then create a new compressed file with the modified file.

It is pssible that a program does this transprently for you so that it seems that you directly modify the file in the compressed file.

This extract, modify, compress scheme is needed as the compressed file depends on all the content. You cannot simply change a file (with different size) inside a compressed file as all pointers in the compressed file must be adjused in this case (also you have to *move* the other files in the copressed file which is programmatically copying the content to a new file).

Comment: can you pls specify what means a program does this transparently for me? you mean a prg does the extraction job for me?

Comment: @huiwang a program can decompress the file in the background, open the file for you to modify it and the compresses the file again after saving.

Comment: what's the name of this program then, is it imbedded with zip or rar?

Comment: @huiwang when I'm using **nautilus** for example I can _mount_ the zip file and do such changes. **nautilus** is a file explorer for linux. It is possible that similar programs exists for windows, but I don't know these.

Comment: There's Zipster, for Mac - I don't know of a Windows one either.

Comment: @UwePlonus what's 'mount'?

Comment: @Tetsujin for windows is zip and rar

Comment: I know what the formats are, just not a utility that can use them 'live'